# HP monitor gets Full HD in Windows, does not get Full HD with Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, monitors

I have a new [HP 22es](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05300181) monitor which supports 1920x1080 (Full HD). When I plug it in to a laptop running Ubuntu 18.10 via VGA, it's in 1024x768 resolution.

I got dual OS on my computer so I tried on Windows side and it gives the picture in Full HD as it should be. I also tried it via HDMI with VGA to HDMI converter but it didn't give any picture at all. So, I am stuck at this point right now and don't know how to get picture in Full HD resolution.

I have written some drivers in the past so I have a little experience on the kernel side, but I am looking for easy solution.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

xrandr --verbose
VGA-1 connected 1024x768+0+140 (0x61) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
        Identifier: 0x43
        Timestamp:  10740021
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
        Brightness: 1.0
        Clones:    
        CRTC:       1
        CRTCs:      0 1 2
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
  1024x768 (0x61) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x70) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x71) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  848x480 (0x9b) 33.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  31.02KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x7f) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

Comment: What GPU/drivers are you using? What does `xrandr` report? Please add to your question.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: figure out the exact model of the GPU and try to find Linux drivers for it (maybe your Windows install will have that info if you don't have the MB manual handy). I've never had one of these built-in GPUs, so I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: It's Intel HD Graphics https://01.org/linuxgraphics such as are built into the Intel R3-1200 APU, and the i915 driver https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/gpu/i915.html is appropriate.